# Java generics Strange behavior

Tags: java, generics

In Java [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) extends [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)

Then next code is **compiling:**

```
List<Number> list1 = null;
List<? super Integer> list2 = null;
list2 = list1;
```

While this code is **not compiling:**

```
List<? super Number> list1 = null;
List<? extends Integer> list2= null;
list1 = list2;
```

The question is why?

Comment: Did you notice that your assignments are reversed in both the codes. Change the first code to - `list1 = list2`, and it won't compile too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what would go wrong if it would have compiled:

```
// Suppose list1, and list2 are initialized like this
List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();  // valid assignment
List<? extends Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // valid

// had this been valid, list1 and list2 both point to ArrayList<Integer>
list1 = list2;   

// This is fine, as list1 declared type is `List<? super Number>`
list1.add(new Float(2.4f));

// The below code will compile fine, as list2.get(0) type is Integer.
// But it would throw ClassCastException at runtime.
Integer in = list2.get(0);
```

So, to avoid it runtime, compiler gives you a compile time error.

For the first case however, you have somehow reversed the assignment, so the comparison between the 2 codes doesn't make sense. Change the first code to:

```
List<Number> list1 = null;
List<? super Integer> list2 = null;
list1 = list2;
```

and it will fail too.

Also, reversing the assignment in the 2nd code would also make the code fail to compile.

**Some explanation:**

What you must remember is, a super class reference can point to a subclass object, but not the reverse. If all the lists that can be capture-converted from `list1` are also capture convertible from the declared type of `list2`, then the assignment `list2 = list1` would be valid, else it would fail to compile.

**For the first code:**

- `List<? super Integer>` can be capture converted to the following lists:

  - `List<Integer>`
  - `List<Number>`
  - `List<Object>`
  - `List<Serializable>`

Since `List<Number>` is there in the list, so assignment `list2 = list1` is valid, as `list1` can only point to a `List<Number>`. But, the reverse assignment `list1 = list2` is not valid, as `List<Integer>` is not a subtype of `List<Number>`.

**Similarly, for the 2nd code:**

- `List<? super Number>` can be capture-converted to:

  - `List<Object>`
  - `List<Serializable>`
  - `List<Number>`
- `List<? extends Integer>` can be capture-converted to:

  - `List<Integer>`

Since `List<Integer>` is not capture-convertible from `List<? super Number>`, so `list1 = list2` is invalid.

Also, since `List<Object>` and all other lists are not capture-convertible from `List<? extends Integer>`, so `list2 = list1` is also invalid.

Comment: @Bohemian Just saw that his first code has assignment in different direction. So, that would compile. Changing it to `list1 = list2` would fail.

Answer (score 0):

(1) In the first example, `List<Number>` is "captured" by of `List<? super Integer>`. A `List<Number>` is a `List<? super Integer>`.

(2) But in the second example, `List<? extends Integer>` is *not* captured by `List<? super Number>`.

For example, you can add `Number`s to `List<? super Number>`, but you cannot add non-`Integer` `Number`s to `List<? extends Integer>`.

```
List<? super Number> list1 = new ArrayList<Number>();
list1.add(0.5);     //okay
List<? extends Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list2.add(0.5);    //not okay
```

Therefore, you cannot assign `list1` to be `list2`, since `list2` does not support everything that the type of `list1` should.

Comment: I am not trying to add number to List<? extends Integer>. I am trying to add Integer to List<? super Number> and it's not working

Comment: But @Babibu, if you are to set `list1` as `list2`, the type of `list1` must support all operations of `list2`.

Comment: Nobody is adding anything, there is an attempted assignment.

Comment: @KevinBowersox, correct. I am using `List.add` as an *example* of why the assignment is invalid. Everything that you can do with `list1` in the second example must be able to be done by `list2`.